# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the project skeleton.
Directory: users. testing.py and models.py are in users directory.

For the following code, the mentioned error is generated:

```
from .models import CustomUser
username='Jason'
userLL = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
print(userLL)
last_login = userLL.last_login
print(last_login)
```

Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/vidyaConnect/users/testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models import CustomUser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

If i remove the dot (.) before models, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/vidyaConnect/users/testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import CustomUser
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\vidyaConnect\users\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projectVC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Did you add an `__init__.py` file to the directory?

Comment: Where is this code? How are you calling it?

Comment: Are you doing `python testing.py` from cmd?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes. But its empty.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was using pycharm and just used 'run' to run the file

Comment: Well that is not how you run Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Even if I run 'from .models import CustomUser' in windows powershell, I get the same error.

Comment: Yes. Because that isn't how you run Django either. To get a Django shell, do `python manage.py shell`

Comment: Thank you everyone :)  Solved it by writing 'from users.models import CustomUser'.